# Django Blog - I can't add new comment

Tags: python, django

Problem with a comment system in my Django project.
When I add a new comment in 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000 the page just reloads and nothing happens.
In "blog/views.py" in `post_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):` I guess there is something wrong at `if request.method == 'POST':` and then move on to `else: comment_form = CommentForm()` so that I can only see the page just reloads. However, I don't know how to fix it...
This is a full code of my Django project.
[my github repository](https://github.com/ecrire06/django_website)

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views.generic import ListView
from taggit.models import Tag
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm

def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'page': page, 'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, status='published', publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
    # List of active comments for this post
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # A comment was posted
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
        
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post, 'comments': comments, 'new_comment': new_comment, 'comment_form': comment_form})

def post_share(request, post_id):
    # Retrieve post by id
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form was submitted
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form fields passed validation
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            message = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'ecrire06@korea.ac.kr', [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post, 'form': form, 'sent': sent})

class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'
```

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- title -->
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>

    <!-- date -->
    <p class="date">
        Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    <!-- body-->
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'blog:post_share' post.id %}">
            Share this post
        </a>
    </p>
    <!-- number of comments-->
    {% with comments.count as total_comments %}
        <h2>
            {{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}
        </h2>
    {% endwith %}
    <!-- content of comments -->
    {% for comment in comments %}
        <div class="comments">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">
                Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by {{ comment.name }}
                {{ comment.created }}
            </p>
            {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>There are no comments yet.</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- add comments -->
    <div>
        {% if new_comment %}
            <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
        {% else %}
            <h2>Add a new comment</h2>
            <form methon="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you should put the relevant parts of your code here in the question - not link to an external Github repo which doubtless will be updated in future, thereby rendering it irrelevant for future readers of the question. However I did take the trouble to glance at your repo, and as far as I can see there's a typo in your template, you have `methon="post"` when it should be `method="post"`

Comment: oh I will keep that in mind to put my code in the question. I changed the typo and it works! Thank you so much Zigmond.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).